# scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported: Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme

Tags: scrapy

I collect links from several directories and then insert them into start_urls as a link variable

```
import scrapy


class SplashSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    f = open('text.txt')
    links = f.read()
    name = 'spide'
    start_urls = [str(links)]
    f.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.css('.title::text').extract()
        description = response.css("div#desc").extract()
        title = list(map(str.strip, title))
        description = list(map(str.strip, description))
        yield{
            'Title': title,
            'Main Info': description,
        }
```

but I'm catching an error: `scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported: Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme`

my text.txt file:

```
'https:// url1.com','https:// url2.com', ... , 'https:// url300000.com', 'https:// url300001.com'
```

Comment: Looks like a blank line in your text file.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import scrapy


class SplashSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    with open('text.txt') as f:
        links = f.readlines()
        links = list(map(lambda x: x.strip().replace(' ', ''), links))
    name = 'spider'
    start_urls = links

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.css('.title::text').extract()
        description = response.css("div#desc").extract()
        title = list(map(str.strip, title))
        description = list(map(str.strip, description))
        yield{
            'Title': title,
            'Main Info': description,
        }
```